# Decompose mixture of gamma and gaussian distributions

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I have a data, which looks like mixture of $\gamma$ and Gausian distributions:
[image]

**Could you help me to find parameters of these distributions?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what software is used for fitting and what error measure is minimized when fitting the distributions.

As an example, [STAN reference (v2.14.0)](http://github.com/stan-dev/stan/releases/download/v2.14.0/stan-reference-2.14.0.pdf) provides details on fitting finite mixtures in chapter 12.

Here is a simple code draft adapted for fitting a mixture of Gaussian and Gamma distribution.

```
data {
    int<lower=1> N;  // number of data points
    real y[N]; // observations
}
parameters {
    simplex[2] theta;// mixing proportions
    real phi[4]; // distribution parameters
}
model {
    real ps[2]; // temp for log component densities
    for (n in 1:N) {
        ps[1] = log(theta[1])+ normal_lpdf(y[n] | phi[1], phi[2]);
        ps[2] = log(theta[2])+ gamma_lpdf(y[n] | phi[3], phi[4]);
        target += log_sum_exp(ps);
    }
}
```

The code computes

$p(y|\phi,\theta_1)= \sum_{i=1}^N\log(\theta_1) \mathrm{PDF}_\mathrm{Normal}(y_i|\phi_1,\phi_2) +\log(1-\theta_1) \mathrm{PDF}_\mathrm{Gamma}(y_i|\phi_3,\phi_4) $

and adds it to the log density of the MCMC sampling algorithm.